# How to pass session variable in laravel using api

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, whmcs

Find below the blade file:

```
@foreach($product1['domains']['domain'] as $product)
    <tr role="row">
    <td  class="sorting_desc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column ascending" aria-sort="descending">1</td>
     <td  class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1"aria-label="Browser: activate to sort column ascending">
      <a href=""  style="color:#23b7e5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">      
      {{$product['domainname']}}
      </a>
      </td>
      <td  class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Platform(s): activate to sort column ascending">
     {{$product['regdate']}}
     </td>
     <td  class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Platform(s): activate to sort column ascending">

    {{$product['expirydate']}}
    </td>


    <td  class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Engine version: activate to sort column ascending">Renew</td>

    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Find below the route code:

```
    Route::get('/mydomains','InvoiceTicketController@set');
```

The controller code is given below :

```
class InvoiceTicketController extends Controller
{

    public function set(){
        $product1=Whmcs::GetClientsDomains([]);
        return view('clientlayout.main.mydomains',compact('product1'));
    }
}
```

Suggest me a solution to pass session variable in laravel to display the domains based on the client in my view file.

Comment: Does it throws any error?

Comment: I dont understand what exactly you want

Comment: I need to pass the user id as my session variable.

Comment: Why dont you simple use `Auth::id()` in your blade view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the helper function session().

On the controller you can use like this:

```
$value = $request->session()->get('key');
```

To store the data on the session you can do like this:

```
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');
```

On the views you can use the function session to retrieve the value:

```
{{ session(['key' => 'value']) }}
```